# Why am I getting a nullpointer error.?

Tags: java, android, menu, dialog

After selecting a menu item , I am trying to show a custom dialog, however when I set the the onClickListener (works fine without onClickListner), a nullpointer error is shown. I check for button id typos and everything is correct.

Any Ideas as to why?

```
  public void  unlinkDeviceClick(MenuItem item){

   final Dialog alertDiag = new Dialog(Home.this); 
   alertDiag.setContentView(R.layout.unlinkdialog);
   alertDiag.setTitle("Unlink Device"); 

   Button yes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signout);
   Button cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelsignout);


   final EditText usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
   final EditText passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordField);   
   final TextView descr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.unlinkresults);    


   yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String userName = usernameField.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

        if(checkLoginFields(userName,password)){        
            if(checkCredentials(userName,password)){
                //loadUnlink(); 
                descr.setText("Sucessfully unlinked");
            }
            else{
                showWrongInfo(new View(Home.this));
            }
        }
        else{

        }

       }

   });


   cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDiag.dismiss();
        }

   });


   alertDiag.show();
}
```

//////////////////////Stack trace//////////////////////////////////////

```
    04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(MenuInflater.java:203)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:154)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:964)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder$ActionMenuAdapter$1.onClick(MenuBuilder.java:1565)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3135)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:5055)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2623)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:4603)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1157)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1159)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(ListView.java:2061)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1159)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1159)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1159)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1159)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1159)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.tv.TvWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(TvWindow.java:1161)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.tv.TvWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(TvWindow.java:803)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchKeyEvent(Dialog.java:706)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.tv.TvWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(TvWindow.java:1117)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRoot.java:2902)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRoot.java:2860)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2059)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4083)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(MenuInflater.java:199)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    ... 30 more
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    at com.ameba.api.activityClasses.Home.unlinkDeviceClick(Home.java:604)
04-19 10:30:32.198: E/AndroidRuntime(20386):    ... 33 more
```

Comment: My guess it's because `findViewById(R.id.signout)` returns `null`?

Comment: I checked the id for the signout button and it is indeed correct. Why would it be null?

Comment: signout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the buttons `yes` and `cancel` are in the dialog you'll want to search for them **in** the dialog layout that you set:

```
Button yes = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.signout);
Button cancel = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelsignout);
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean, I created my own custom dialog xml with two buttons yes and cancel.

Comment: You mean like this :dialog.findViewById(R.id.signout) ?

Comment: @Fabii Your buttons exist only in the layout that you set in the dialog `R.layout.unlinkdialog`. If you do `findViewById()` you'll search for them in the current activity layout where you will obviously will not find them and have a `NullPointerException`. You'll have to use `findViewById` on the dialog object where you set the layout that contains your buttons.

Comment: I think @Luksprog guessed it right: the findViewById method looks for the widget hierarchy of its owner. Calling it from your activity means you want a widget in the hierarchy of your activity view. But the Yes / Cancel buttons are in your dialog hierarchy so the correct answer would be alertDiag.findViewById(...)

Answer (score 0):

Without the CallStack, it's hard to tell. One idea though, maybe the widgets you're getting with findViewById are null.

The best thing would be to check the call stack to know if it's the Yes button or Cancel button making the error, or best, use a breakpoint and step by step through your code to find what's missing.